# Creating signed library with ILMerge throwing exception

Tags: .net, ilmerge, assembly-signing

I'm trying to create a merged version of FakeItEasy that includes Castle.Core. I read about ILMerge and it seemed like it was the solution I needed. After downloading and building FakeItEasy I copied all the files I needed (FakeItEasy.dll (.NET4), Castle.Core.dll (.NET4), ilmerge.exe, FakeItEasy.snk) to the same folder. I then ran the following command:

```
ilmerge 
    /keyfile:FakeItEasy.snk 
    /out:..\FakeItEasy.dll 
    /t:library 
    /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 
    FakeItEasy.dll Castle.Core.dll
```

And got the following result:

```
An exception occurred during merging:                                                             
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)                                                                                                
   at System.Compiler.Writer.MscorsnStrongNameSignatureGeneration(String wszFilePath, String wszKeyContainer, Byte[] pbKeyBlob, Int32 cbKeyBlob, IntPtr ppbSignatureBlob, IntPtr pcbSignatureBlob)  
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)                                              
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)        
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()                                                                   
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

If I leave off the "/keyfile:FakeItEasy.snk" the merged assembly is created just fine, but that doesn't help me as I need a signed version.

I've also tried specifying the target platform as:

```
/targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

but the results were the same.

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer to this as I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Never did figure it out. We ended up using the version of FakeItEasy distributed through NuGet so the issue went away.

Comment: A workaround that worked for me was `corflags ilmerge /32bitreq+ /force` to make it to run in 32-bit mode instead of 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this issue when setting up a project on a new machine running Windows 8 64-bit.  I was previously developing in a Windows 7 32-bit virtual machine and had no issue.  The ILMerge command is being run as a post-build event.  Since Visual Studio is a 32-bit process I was also able to replicate the behavior in a 32-bit Visual Studio Command Prompt on the Windows 8 64-bit machine using the same ILMerge command used in the post-build event.

```
ILMerge.exe 
   /keyfile:public.snk 
   /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" 
   /t:exe 
   /ndebug 
   /out:Result.exe Source.exe Other.dll
```

I've done a fair amount of work interfacing .NET applications and native C++ libraries, so I'm very familiar with the exception message `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.` This indicates a bitness issue where, for example, a 32-bit process attempts to load a 64-bit library.  That exact situation is what I believe is going on here.  Since this is a 64-bit machine I also tried the ILMerge command in a 64-bit Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Interestingly, but not totally surprisingly, the same command that generates the exception in the 32-bit prompt works fine in the 64-bit prompt.

I'm using an snk file that contains only public key information when developing, so I'm delay signing the merged assembly.  I then looked at the available command switches for ILMerge and discovered the `/delaysign` switch.  Adding this switch to the ILMerge command alleviates the issue when running ILMerge from a 32-bit process.

```
ILMerge.exe 
   /keyfile:public.snk 
   /delaysign
   /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" 
   /t:exe 
   /ndebug 
   /out:Result.exe Source.exe Other.dll
```

What's even more interesting is that when using an snk file with a full public/private key pair, the ILMerge command works just fine without the `/delaysign` switch.  So it appears that the exception is generated when using an snk file with only public key information and when ILMerge is launched from a 32-bit process.

Comment: Interesting... After repairing a broken Windows 10 installation, I starting seeing this error in a project that had been building fine for years. However it doesn't seem related to bitness, but to admin privileges. When I build from an elevated process, it works, otherwise it fails. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error when I upgraded to VS 2015 from VS 2013 and tried to build a project that had always built fine (ILMerge is executed as part of the build).  The answer above reminded me that private keys require administrative access.  Then I remembered that my new VS 2015 shortcut wasn't setup to "Run as administrator".  Once I restarted VS 2015 as an administrator, the ILMerge part of the build worked fine.